# How to reduce subqueries in a SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that has a number of subqueries and it is slowing it down.  Many of the subqueries are the same record but different fields.  I was wondering if there was a way to query that record once rather than four times.

For example:

```
select 
field1 as (select field1 from people where company = g.company),
field2 as (select field2 from people where company = g.company),
field3 as (select field3 from people where company = g.company),
field4 as (select field4 from people where company = g.company)
from peopleGroup g
```

Comment: Just join the record on.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: BTW, rows and columns, not records or fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subquerying in the SELECT clause has its uses, but it's generally an exception to solve a problem. Instead the proper way to do what you are doing is to join your two tables properly in your FROM clause:

```
SELECT people.field1, people.field2, people.field3, people.field4
FROM peopleGroup g
    LEFT OUTER JOIN people
         ON g.company = people.company
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to subquery for whatever reason (let's say a `TOP 1`) then you can use an `APPLY`

```sql
select 
  p.field1,
  p.field2,
  p.field3,
  p.field4
from peopleGroup g
outer apply (
    select
      p.field1,
      p.field2,
      p.field3,
      p.field4
    from people p
    where p.company = g.company
) p;
```

`OUTER APPLY` simulates a `LEFT JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY` simulates a `INNER JOIN`